# how to create variable name within a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop

```
x<-as.factor(c("ds","sd","ds","dd"))
fn<-function(x){
results<-list(a=c(2,3,4),b=c("3","d"))
for(i in 1:length(levels(x))){
results<-list(results,
assign(paste("g", i, sep = ""), levels(x)[i]))
  }
return(results)
}
fn(x)
 [[1]]
 [[1]][[1]]
 [[1]][[1]][[1]]
 [[1]][[1]][[1]]$a
 [1] 2 3 4

 [[1]][[1]][[1]]$b
 [1] "3" "d"


 [[1]][[1]][[2]]
 [1] "dd"


 [[1]][[2]]
 [1] "ds"


 [[2]]
 [1] "sd"
```

The above output is not what I want. I want it to be like the following output

```
$a
[1] 2 3 4
$b
"3" "d"
$g1
"dd"
$g2
"ds"
$g3
"sd"
```

The name of the list in the output is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the reasoning is behind your question but this can be done without any for loop. Please, try

```
x <- as.factor(c("ds", "sd", "ds", "dd"))
results <- list(a = c(2, 3, 4), b = c("3", "d"))
results <- c(results, setNames(as.list(levels(x)), paste0("g", seq_len(nlevels(x)))))

results
```

to recreate the expected result:

> ```
> $a
> [1] 2 3 4
>
> $b
> [1] "3" "d"
>
> $g1
> [1] "dd"
>
> $g2
> [1] "ds"
>
> $g3
> [1] "sd"
> ```

The levels of `x`are coerced from vector to a list. Then the list elements are renamed using `setNames()`. The names are given as a character vector created by pasting together `g` and a sequence of numbers which runs from 1 to the number of levels in `x`. Finally, this new list is appended to the existing `result` list.

Comment: It must be in a loop because it is a function fn(), and the x object is not known. the levels of this factor can be any number. in the case the number of  level of x is 3, but it can be 4, 5, or 6. then a loop is mandatory to accormodate  any number of levels.

Comment: You are right, I shouldn't have hardcoded the number of levels. Please, see my updated version which works with any number of levels - still without `for` loop.